# Decision trees and Curse of Dimensionality

Tags: classification, decision-trees, dimensionality-reduction

Since decision tree algorithm splits the training dataset one feature at a time, how the heck is possibly that it suffers from curse of dimensionality ?

Comment: Since you will have a lot of dimensions to split on and adding more and more might help(who knows).. But we generally select randomly some columns while building it acc to different algos

Answer (score 1):

Every machine learning algorithm suffers from the curse of dimensionality to different degrees. The primary issue is the sparsity of observations as the number of dimensions increases.

Since decision trees are greedy, they are one of the most robust machine learning algorithms to sparsity. Decision trees will always find the single feature that creates the most pure regions. This process is recursively repeated. Decision trees learn to ignore less informative dimensions.